# Handling Cookies with OkHttp/Retrofit - Cannot resolve symbol 'Preferences'

Tags: java, android, cookies

Hey I need some help with "okhttp". I want to store the cookie I get from my request to reuse it later in the app. I came across this example but the problem is I don't know in which package the `Preferences` class is. How can I can import it? If I use autocomplete I can use  `import java.util.prefs.Preferences;`. But it is not the android one. It doesn't contain the `getDefaultPreferences()` method. See the code in the link below.

on line 12 in `AddCookiesInterceptor.java` :

```
HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences
    .getDefaultPreferences()
    .getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
```

http://tsuharesu.com/handling-cookies-with-okhttp/

```
/**
 * This interceptor put all the Cookies in Preferences in the Request.
 * Your implementation on how to get the Preferences MAY VARY.
 * <p>
 * Created by tsuharesu on 4/1/15.
 */
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet) Preferences.getDefaultPreferences().getStringSet(Preferences.PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<>());
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            Log.v("OkHttp", "Adding Header: " + cookie); // This is done so I know which headers are being added; this interceptor is used after the normal logging of OkHttp
        }

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that you are seeing two typos. `Preferences` -> `PreferenceManager`, and `getSharedPreferences()` -> `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Preferences is not a typo, he just copied the code and expected to work - even though it is wrote there that how he gets Preferences may vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a `PreferenceManager` class which has a `mSharedPreferences` member variable. Instantiate `mSharedPreferences` by calling `mApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(name, mode)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.trainerworkout.trainerworkout.network;

import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * This interceptor put all the Cookies in Preferences in the Request.
 * Your implementation on how to get the Preferences MAY VARY.
 */
public class AddCookiesInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    public static final String PREF_COOKIES = "PREF_COOKIES";
    private Context context;

    public AddCookiesInterceptor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    } // AddCookiesInterceptor()

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        HashSet<String> preferences = (HashSet<String>) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getStringSet(PREF_COOKIES, new HashSet<String>());
        for (String cookie : preferences) {
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            Log.v("OkHttp", "Adding Header: " + cookie); // This is done so I know which headers are being added; this interceptor is used after the normal logging of OkHttp
        } // for

        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    } // intercept()
} // AddCookiesInterceptor
```

Somewhere you create a new OkHttpClient and use it on all your requests.

```
public static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
private OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

builder.addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor(context));
builder.addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor(context));
client = builder.build();
```

Comment: Do you have ReceivedCookiesInterceptor?

Comment: Yes, it is in the project.